# How can I save images in my server with their default name using PHP?

Tags: php, image, save

I would like to know how can I save images from an URL in "images" directory of my server with their default or original names.
The images that I want to save are in two types of URL, the most common one who shows the image name and extension, and the others wich hide it.

Example:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/t31.0-8/p960x960/12244276_1007140432640240_2083118789257532219_o.jpg

[https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/11070008_891891757498442_2110055736558514695_n.jpg?oh=aed45e8772757a932e8001f2024be09d&oe=57169246&**gda**=1459966832_bd13f474178cc030348f8fdc0dc0eafd](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/11070008_891891757498442_2110055736558514695_n.jpg?oh=aed45e8772757a932e8001f2024be09d&oe=57169246&__gda__=1459966832_bd13f474178cc030348f8fdc0dc0eafd)

...and the names wich I want to save they with is the default one that appears when you right click on they and select "save image as...", in this case: 12244276_1007140432640240_2083118789257532219_o.jpg and 11070008_891891757498442_2110055736558514695_n.jpg respectively.

I've tryng with something like pathinfo function but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$partes_ruta = pathinfo('https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/t31.0-8/p960x960/12244276_1007140432640240_2083118789257532219_o.jpg');

echo $partes_ruta['dirname'], "\n";
echo $partes_ruta['basename'], "\n";
echo $partes_ruta['extension'], "\n";
echo $partes_ruta['filename'], "\n"; // desde PHP 5.2.0

?>
```

Since I've got a spanish navigator its always says error: "La codificación de caracteres del documento HTML no fue declarada. El documento se verá con basura en el texto en algunas configuraciones de navegadores si el documento contiene caracteres fuera del rango US-ASCII. La codificación de caracteres de la página debe declararse en el documento o en el protocolo de transferencia."
Its means something like the character coding info of HTML document was not declared, document may be displayed dirty if it has characters out of the US-ASCII range. Characters coding must be declared.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What do u mean by `it doesnt work? you should provide some code and effort u have done so far`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You say you've tried using the pathinfo function -- could you please post your code with more details?

Comment: Thanks, your questions make me re-read the error! I I thought that the problem couldnt be for this, but I try anyway and works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that script works if I add the HTML code, I don't know why is this neede since page is a php one, but it works by this way.

```
<?php

$partes_ruta = pathinfo('https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtf1/t31.0-8/p960x960/12244276_1007140432640240_2083118789257532219_o.jpg');
echo $partes_ruta['basename'], "\n";

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to parse the URL with `explode`

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
@mkdir("images");
$end = end(explode("/", $url));
file_put_contents("images/$end", $output);
```